# How to get the value of a child in Firebase?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to get the riderId value from my database:

[image]

The code I am using to get it:

```
Query query = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference(Common.user_rider_tbl);
            query.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    riderId = String.valueOf(dataSnapshot.getChildren().child("riderId"));
                    Log.d(TAG, "riderId = " + riderId);
                }
```

What am I doing wrong to get the value of riderId?

**json**

```
"Riders" : {
  "C0RjB5NPZcTvWz9XiUAhpTDOK0C2" : {
    "avatarUrl" : "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/ryyde-sj.appspot.com/o/images%2Friders%2F0badce3c-e75b-4d52-88e1-d2009090fb73?alt=media&token=5ca59575-54ce-401e-ac27-c1d4e6a5f94c",
    "email" : "rider@me.com",
    "name" : "Rider1",
    "password" : "zzzzzz",
    "phone" : "665",
    "rates" : "0",
    "riderId" : "C0RjB5NPZcTvWz9XiUAhpTDOK0C2"
  },
```

Comment: what is the value of Common.user_rider_tbl?

Comment: the value is "Users/Riders"

Comment: dataSnapshot.getChild()?

Comment: or wait, you have a list of rider ids, correct?

Comment: I do, but I only want the current rider

Comment: you have to specify the current one's id then. Users/Riders/CurrentRider

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont know what is current user's id, but we can assume this

```
riderId = dataSnapshot.child(CurrentRiderID).child("riderId").getValue(String.class);
```

Comment: .child is in red - cannot resolve method 'java.lang.String"

Comment: the for loop is going through all the ids, I only want the current user riderId

Comment: the problem is that Common.user_rider_tbl this variable needs to have a current rider's id

Comment: right, but I don't know how to get it.  I am in another device trying to access the users riderId from another user - driver.  The project in firebase has 2 apps in one database

Comment: hmm if you have a list of riders, how do you know which one is yours?

Comment: I have another node called "Requests" which has the current riderId.  I am trying to save to that node but I need the riderId in order to do that.  So I thought if I get the riderId from "Users/Riders"

Comment: if you can replace the CurrentRiderID to the actual id that you said you have, the above code should do it

Answer (score 0):

Use getValue method

```
riderId = dataSnapshot.child("riderId").getValue(String.class);
```

I guess you want to fetch parent key ..so you can also use

```
dataSnapshot.getKey();
```

In this way you won't have to make extra node for it